# Drop down list is causing an error on the jsp page

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

I was trying to create the drop-down list to delete the booktag value by retrieving the data and using  the remove function from the DAO class but it made this error: "java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "isbn13" ".  I have found out that the servlet must gain access to the name attribute so I inserted  this code `int isbn13ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("booktag"));`. But the problem is that eclipse tells me that the variable is unused so I am not sure what else to do for the select tag to gain access to the servlet variable. Here is code:

JSP:

```html
    <!-- Header -->
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
<!-- JSTL includes -->
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>



<header>
<div class="container">
    


<h1>PUBHUB <small>Add Booktag</small></h1>
        <hr class="book-primary">

        
        <form action="AddBookTag" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="isbn13" class="col-sm-4 control-label">ISBN 13</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="isbn13" name="isbn13" placeholder="ISBN 13" required="required" value="${param.isbn13 }" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nametag" class="col-sm-4 control-label">NameTag</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nametag" name="nametag" placeholder="NameTag" required="required" value="${param.nametag }" />
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</header>           
<section>
<div class="container">

<h1><small>Delete Booktag</small></h1>
 
 <form action="DeleteBookTag" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
    <select name="booktag">
    <c:forEach items="${booktags}" var="booktag">
        <option value="${booktags.isbn13}">${booktags.isbn13}</option>
        <option value="${booktags.nameTag}">${booktags.nameTag}</option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

AddBookTag Servlet:

```html
package examples.pubhub.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;



import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import examples.pubhub.model.BookTag;
import examples.pubhub.dao.BookTagDAO;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

@WebServlet("/AddBookTag")

public class AddBookTagServlet extends HttpServlet {

    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("").forward(request, response);
    }
    
    
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        //String isbn13 = req.getParameter("isbn13");
        
        BookTagDAO database = DAOUtilities.getBookTagDAO();
        BookTag bookTag = new BookTag();
        bookTag.setIsbn13(req.getParameter("isbn13"));
        bookTag.setNameTag(req.getParameter("nametag"));
        
        
        boolean isSuccess = database.addNameTag(bookTag);
        
        if(isSuccess){
            req.getSession().setAttribute("message", "Book Tag successfully added");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-success");

            // We use a redirect here instead of a forward, because we don't
            // want request data to be saved. Otherwise, when
            // a user clicks "refresh", their browser would send the data
            // again!
            // This would be bad data management, and it
            // could result in duplicate rows in a database.
            resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/AddBookTag");
        }else {
            req.getSession().setAttribute("message", "There was a problem publishing the book");
            req.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-danger");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("bookTag.jsp").forward(req, resp);
        
    
        
        
    }
}
}
```

BookTAG Servlet

```html
package examples.pubhub.servlets;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



import examples.pubhub.model.BookTag;
import examples.pubhub.dao.BookTagDAO;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

@WebServlet("/BookTag")
public class BookTagServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        //Populates the drop down list
        
        
        BookTagDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getBookTagDAO();
        
        List<BookTag>tagList = dao.getAllBookTags();
        
        request.getSession().setAttribute("booktags", tagList);
        
        request.getRequestDispatcher("bookTag.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    
}
```

Delete BookTag Servlet

```html
package examples.pubhub.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;





import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


import examples.pubhub.model.BookTag;
import examples.pubhub.dao.BookTagDAO;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;

@WebServlet("/DeleteBookTag")
public class DeleteBookTagServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        boolean isSuccess = false;
        
        String isbn13 = request.getParameter("isbn13");
        String nameTag = request.getParameter("nametag");
        
        BookTag booktag = new BookTag();
        
        booktag.setIsbn13(isbn13);
        booktag.setNameTag(nameTag);
        
        
        BookTagDAO dao = DAOUtilities.getBookTagDAO();
        
         
        isSuccess = dao.removeNameTag(booktag);
         
        int isbn13ID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("booktag"));
        
        
        
        if(isSuccess){
            request.getSession().setAttribute("message", "Book successfully deleted");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-success");
            response.sendRedirect("ViewBookDetails?isbn13=" + isbn13);
        }else {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("message", "There was a problem deleting this booktag");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("messageClass", "alert-danger");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("bookTag.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }       
        
    
    }
    
    
    
    
    }
```

BookTag DAO class

```html
package examples.pubhub.dao;





import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import examples.pubhub.model.BookTag;
import examples.pubhub.model.Book;
import examples.pubhub.utilities.DAOUtilities;


public class BookTagDAOImpl implements BookTagDAO {

    Connection connection = null;   // Our connection to the database
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;  // We use prepared statements to help protect against SQL injection
    
    
    @Override
    public List<BookTag>getAllBookTags(){
        
        List<BookTag>bookTags = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            connection = DAOUtilities.getConnection();  // Get our database connection from the manager
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM book_tag";          // Our SQL query
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);    // Creates the prepared statement from the query
            
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();         // Queries the database

            // So long as the ResultSet actually contains results...
            while (rs.next()) {
                // We need to populate a Book object with info for each row from our query result
                BookTag bookTag = new BookTag();

                // Each variable in our Book object maps to a column in a row from our results.
                bookTag.setIsbn13(rs.getString("isbn_13"));
                bookTag.setNameTag(rs.getString("name_tag"));
                
                // Finally we add it to the list of Book objects returned by this query.
                bookTags.add(bookTag);
                
            }
            
            rs.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // We need to make sure our statements and connections are closed, 
            // or else we could wind up with a memory leak
            closeResources();
        }
        
        
        return bookTags;
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    @Override
    public List<BookTag> getNameTagsByBook(String isbn13) {
        List<BookTag> booktags = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            connection = DAOUtilities.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM book_tag WHERE isbn_13 = ?";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
             stmt.setString(1,isbn13);  
            
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                
            BookTag booktag = new BookTag();
                
            booktag.setNameTag(rs.getString("name_tag"));   
            
            booktag.setIsbn13(rs.getString("isbn_13")); 
            
            booktags.add(booktag);  
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeResources();
        }
        
        
        
        return booktags;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBookByNameTag(String nameTag) {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    
        try {
            connection = DAOUtilities.getConnection();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM books\r\n"
                    + "LEFT JOIN book_tag ON books.isbn_13=book_tag.isbn_13\r\n"
                    + "WHERE name_tag = ?";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, nameTag); 
            
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()) {
                
            //BookTag booktag = new BookTag();
            Book  book = new Book();
            
            book.setIsbn13(rs.getString("isbn_13"));
            book.setAuthor(rs.getString("author"));
            book.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            book.setPublishDate(rs.getDate("publish_date").toLocalDate());
            book.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            book.setContent(rs.getBytes("content"));
            
            
            books.add(book);    
            
            //books.add(book);
            }
            
            
            
            
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            closeResources();
        }
        
        
    
        return books;
    }
       
    
    
    @Override
    public boolean addNameTag(BookTag booktag) {
        try {
            connection = DAOUtilities.getConnection();
            String sql = "INSERT INTO book_tag VALUES (?, ?)"; // Were using a lot of ?'s here...
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            // But that's okay, we can set them all before we execute
            stmt.setString(1, booktag.getNameTag());
            stmt.setString(2, booktag.getIsbn13());
            
        
            
            // If we were able to add our book to the DB, we want to return true. 
            // This if statement both executes our query, and looks at the return 
            // value to determine how many rows were changed
            if (stmt.executeUpdate() != 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            closeResources();
        }
        
    }
     
    @Override 
    public boolean removeNameTag(BookTag booktag) {
        try {
            connection = DAOUtilities.getConnection();
            String sql = "DELETE book_tag WHERE name_tag=? AND isbn_13=?";
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            
            
            stmt.setString(1, booktag.getNameTag());
            stmt.setString(2, booktag.getIsbn13());
            if (stmt.executeUpdate() != 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            closeResources();
        }
    }

    
    private void closeResources() {
        try {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not close statement!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        try {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not close connection!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Dao code for deletion seems ill-designed: it should take a single unique identifier for the `BookTag` to be deleted. You would use that as `<option>` `value` in your drop-down list.

Anyway, you can't pass 2 separate values from a `<select>` in a `<form>`. If you really need both the name and ISBN13 fields for deletion, then concatenate both in the `<option>` `value` attribute, and then split them apart in your `DeleteBookTagServlet`

**JSP**

```html
<h1><small>Delete Booktag</small></h1>

<form action="DeleteBookTag" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
  <select name="booktag">
    <c:forEach items="${booktags}" var="booktag">
      <option value="${booktags.isbn13};<c:out value="${booktags.nameTag}" />">
        ${booktags.isbn13}
        -
        <c:out value="${booktags.nameTag}" />
      </option>
    </c:forEach>
  </select>
</form>
```

**DeleteBookTagServlet.java**

```java
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  ...
  
  final String selectedOption = request.getParameter("booktag");
  if (selectedOption == null)
   return; //TODO: Manage error
  
  final String[] spl = selectedOption.trim().split("\\s*;\\s*", 2);
  if (spl.length < 2)
    return; //TODO: Manage error
  
  final String isbn13 = spl[0];
  final String nameTag = spl[1];
  
  final BookTag booktag = new BookTag();
  booktag.setIsbn13(isbn13);
  booktag.setNameTag(nameTag);

  //Perform deletion and redirect
  ...
}
```